# removing dynamic controls from the panel

Tags: c#

I have dynamically generated controls on the panels of windows form and i have also generated a button for removing the controls,
controls are on a line code is,

```
    int c = 0;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int v;
        v = c++;
        panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = VerticalScroll.Minimum;
        ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
        combo.Name = "combobox" + v ;
        combo.Location = new Point(30, 5 + (30 * v));

        ComboBox combo2 = new ComboBox();
        combo2.Name = "combobox2" + v ;
        combo2.Location = new Point(170, 5 + (30 * v));

        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.Name = "txtbx" + v;
        txt.Location = new Point(300, 5 + (30 * v));

        TextBox txt2 = new TextBox();
        txt2.Name = "txtbx2" + v;
        txt2.Location = new Point(450, 5 + (30 * v));

        TextBox txt3 = new TextBox();
        txt3.Name = "txtbx3" + v;
        txt3.Location = new Point(600, 5 + (30 * v));

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Name = "btn" + v;
        btn.Text = "Remove";
        btn.Location = new Point(750, 5 + (30 * v));



        panel1.Controls.Add(combo);
        panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
        panel1.Controls.Add(txt);
        panel1.Controls.Add(combo2);
        panel1.Controls.Add(txt2);
        panel1.Controls.Add(txt3);
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);

    }
    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // what i have to write here for removing only the textbox and combobox and  button itself to be removed only the controls which are  aside the button

    }
```

what i have to write in the button click event for removing only the textbox and combobox and button itself to be removed the controls which are aside the button other line controls should not be effected by that,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(var item in panel1.Controls)
{

    if(item is TextBox || item is ComboBox)
    {
          panel1.Controls.Remove(item);
    }


}
```

Or alternatively you could try this below.

```
 var list = (from object item in panel1.Controls where item is TextBox || item is ComboBox select item as Control).ToList();

            list.ForEach(x => panel1.Controls.Remove(x));
```

Comment: And what about the Button in your solution?

Comment: he best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Remove(System.Windows.Forms.Cont‌​rol)' has some invalid argument

Comment: This will not work, since you are changing the collection while looping through it at the same time. This will result in skiping items.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes just seen your comment. tried it out and didn't get any errors but i've modified my answer to include an alternative way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the Control by Name inside the containing Element.

This depends on which framework you develop. C# is not very helpful ;)

Then you can Remove it with

```
SomeParentElement.Comtrols.Remove(SomeElement)
```

Comment: can you help me that the control is dynamically generated so how to find the name of the control as it have many names one by one, and i have to remove the control which are in line

Comment: Are you developing with WinForms?